# jQuery post not working on safari but works on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, safari

i've been facing a safari issue where a JQuery post method works on chrome but it does not on safari unless i set JQuery post async to false with this piece of code

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
```

also page redirect does not work on safari, but it works on chrome

```
window.location.href = data.url;
```

any idea why i'm getting this behavior on safari and how to fixe it.
here is the code that i'm using

```
  $('#submit').click(  function () {  //post 
        if ($('form').validate().checkForm() === false) {
            alert('Form is invalid.');
            return;
        }

        var tool = $("#Tool").val();
        var email = $("#Email").val();
        var message = $("#Message").val();
        var attachement0 = $("#Attachement0").val();
        var attachement1 = $("#Attachement1").val();
        var attachement2 = $("#Attachement2").val();
        var attachement3 = $("#Attachement3").val();
        var attachement4 = $("#Attachement4").val();

        var dataToPost = {};
        dataToPost.Tool = tool;
        dataToPost.Email = email;
        dataToPost.Message = message;
        dataToPost.Attachement0 = attachement0;
        dataToPost.Attachement1 = attachement1;
        dataToPost.Attachement2 = attachement2;
        dataToPost.Attachement3 = attachement3;
        dataToPost.Attachement4 = attachement4;

      // $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
       $.post("@Url.Action("BugReport_Send_JQuery","BugReport")", { model: dataToPost }).done(function (data) {
           if (data.status == 1) {
               alert(data.message);
               window.location.href = data.url;
           }
           else if (data.status == 0) alert(data.error);
       });
    });
```

server side post method

```
      [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BugReport_Send_JQuery(User_BugReportViewModel model)  
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var bugReport = new BugReportModel()
            {
                Tool = model.Tool,
                Email = model.Email,
                Message = model.Message,
                Attachement0 = model.Attachement0,
                Attachement1 = model.Attachement1,
                Attachement2 = model.Attachement2,
                Attachement3 = model.Attachement3,
                Attachement4 = model.Attachement4,
                Resolved = false,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                ResolutionDate = new DateTime(),
            };

            try
            {
                await appDBContext.BugReportsTB.AddAsync(bugReport);
                await appDBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { status = 0, error = e.Message });
            }

            return Json(
            new
            {
                status = 1,
                message = "A ticket has been created, Thank you for your coperations!",
                url = Url.Action("TicketCreate", "Email", new { email = bugReport.Email }),
            });
        }
        return Json(new { status = 0, error = "something went wrong!" });
    }
```

Comment: Never ever use `async: false`. It is a horrible practice and has been deprecated by browser vendors many of which will log deprecation warnings in console when used

Comment: i know it is dirty, i'm looking for a good clean solution to this issue

Comment: chrome is the modern day internet explorer. It plays by it's own rules. Good luck figuring out why your code works everywhere but chrome.

Comment: you didn't read my issue, my code works on chrome, it does not on safari

Comment: Shouldn't the redirect instead be: `window.location` ? The `href` returns the current page url: `window.location.href returns the href (URL) of the current page`

Comment: `window.location`is not working as well, i ended up doing the post request and page redirect with asp.net and the partial posts request "attachement uploads" with Ajax, it seams like post requests with page redirect with ajax is not a good idea , ps i'm new to this